# The requests for the following URLs don't fit in a single packet. Reducing the size of these requests could reduce latency

Tags: css, fonts, web, pingdom

Pingdom Speed test tool showing below error : Minimize request size

The requests for the following URLs don't fit in a single packet. Reducing the size of these requests could reduce latency.

```
data:application/font-woff;base64,d09GRgABAAAAA ... mMrFlnJ5aXLN8srxynGxmBgfv9d+AQ8KdggAAAABVwJMPAAA
```

[Screenshot Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZkLm.png)

Answer (score 3):

This is a problem of Pingdom, not of your website. If you're using Wordpress, the standard WordPress Twenty-whatever themes generate the same diagnostic.

There's no need to fix it. I suggest using Google's Page Speed Insights rather than Pingdom and Google doesn't recognise this as a problem at all.